# express-session: send extra detail in 401 response

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

I am using express-session and was wondering if its possible to send some additional details in the 401 response express will send back when a session is no longer found.

I would like to distinguish when a session has expired vs when no session is found, so I can send some extra details in the response body that the client can use to then show some information text to the user that their session has expired.

Is this possible?

Hopefully I am making sense with this question!

Comment: You can do it by `res.status(401); res.render('401page')` ?

Comment: I'm not so sure that will help me here

Comment: You can set status of response to `401` and send some json as `res.json({'message': 'Unauthorized'})` in case of api.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, then you can send some json with status `401` to let client know more about the issue.
e.g.

```
res.status(401);
res.json({'message': 'session has expired'});
```

Comment: That's fine for sending your own custom 401 response, but I want to be able to hook into the point at which express-session causes the 401 response to be sent (I think)

Comment: You can write error handler in middleware that will receive all errors. In that handler, you can check `401` status and send custom data.